# NoSuchElement: Unable to locate element

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find element in my webpage using `findElement()` function. But i got the following error -

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12127/devtools/browser/92800bba-de09-487a-93c4-61053590a4a2
(node:4944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="captchaimg"]"}
```

After that i thought maybe its because of asynchronous way of execution, so tried using `wait()` function but the error remains.

Code -

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
driver.get("https://www.imsnsit.org/imsnsit/student.htm");

driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated({xpath: '//*[@id="captchaimg"]'}));
var img = driver.findElement({xpath: '//*[@id="captchaimg"]'});

var link = img.getAttribute('src');
console.log(link);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the HTML ?

Comment: @Prany the link for webpage is in the code

Comment: Please add the HTML as the URL says Please use latest version of Chrome browser to access the Application.. and I don't have chrome

Comment: @Prany here is the link to downloaded copy of webpage, i am not uploading the whole html as it might get too big

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m-qOBZXkCIOcS6naRsFakalPyQi2ba7w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you use CSS instead of Xpath which is 'td.plum_field > div'

Comment: The element you are looking for resides within a frame . You need to switch to the target frame first using  webdriver before you can lookup the element.